# Atmel Qtouch library help

Tags: avr, touch-panel

I'm trying to have 3 touch sensitive buttons on an ATtiny48 device using Qtouch library.

The code was generated using the library wizard inside Atmel studio. I've only added a single condition to act when touch is sensed (only a single button is checked in this code).

```
int main( void )
{
    init_system();
    init_timer_isr();
    touch_init();
    __enable_interrupt();

    DDRD |= (1<<PD0);

    while(1)
    {
        touch_measure();

        if (GET_SENSOR_STATE(0))
            PORTD |= (1<<PD0);
        else
            PORTD &= ~(1<<PD0);
    }
}
```

As for the hardware, I've used 10nF film cap. across the button outputs and the sense pad is connected using a 12k resistor. Please see below:
[image]

I can see pulses on the sensing pins but nothing else. I'm not even sure how the generated code knows the system clock freq. for correct timer operation.

Comment: The `init_system()` call has most of the set-up code for the timers in use and setting up the system clock.

Comment: @RonBeyer Do you have any feedback for the hardware side? Layout or part selection? Something that would make the circuit not work?

Comment: The hardware side is difficult to determine from pictures, an actual schematic would help significantly. Did you look through some of the Atmel QTouch demo board schematics? I have an Atmel UC3-A3 XPlained kit on my desk with QTouch, but haven't personally played around with that part of it.